# How to get event on which div data is scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can we get scroll position on which div it is scrolling ? In other word I have two divs in a parent div.I want to print on console on which div I am scrolling the data .If I scrolling in div 1 it print div1 and if I scroll in div 2 print 2.
I have 2 divs preRealTimeContents and RealTimeContents  .can we get this event.?

http://jsfiddle.net/R5Lrw/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#fullContainer').on('scroll', function () {
                         alert('===')

                           });
```

})

Comment: You scroll them both at the same time. When to change the target?

Comment: Actually When I am scrolling contend I need the div on which I am scrolling

Comment: Looks like I've partly misunderstood your question ; ). You want the element under mouse pointer while scrolling? What if user scrolls using the scrollbar? [A fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/5jFMU/), how to get the element from top-left corner of `#fullContainer`. You can also omit the debouncer, and use `onScroll()` as an eventhandler alone. In a quick-test it seems that mouse position can't be detected while scrolling nor with `onmousewheel`, I'll investigate further...

Comment: @Teemu fast answer do you have another option ?

Comment: Maybe, but first I've to know, what you actually need : ).

Comment: can you use fiddle :)

Comment: I already tell you ..i need visible div id when i am scrolling

Comment: @Teemu can we get Id of upper div when both div are visible ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you might find this library useful:

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

This allows you to determine when you have scrolled to a particular element. So in your case, you could do something like:

```
$('#preRealTimeContents ').waypoint(function(direction) {
  alert('In preRealTimeContents');
});

$('#RealTimeContents ').waypoint(function(direction) {
  alert('In RealTimeContents');
});
```

Comment: I need If I scroll in RealTimeContents it print RealTimeContents.If I scroll in preRealTimeContents than it print in preRealTimeContents

Comment: Do you need it to print for every scroll event (which will be a lot) or just when those `div`s are reached?

Comment: yes ..can we get on which div my scroll position is there

Answer (score 0):

This snippet logs an id of the topmost element within `#fullContainer`:

```
$('#fullContainer').on('scroll', function (e) {
     console.log(document.elementFromPoint(this.offsetLeft + 1, this.offsetTop + 1).id);
});
```

Correct value for constant `1` depends on your padding/margin/border styling. I've added a couple of `br`s to the HTML, just to show, what happens in such case.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jFMU/10/).